# Toggle visibility of MVC table rows based on id

Tags: javascript, ajax, toggle, row, visibility

In my MVC Razor view I have a table with rows representing two levels of a hierarchy. Each row can be clicked to load a partialview content area by an ajax call. This works fine.

To have a more compact list I would now like to turn the table into a "light collapsable treeview". Rows in the second level should only be visible when their header row is clicked. When another header row is clicked, all current sub rows should be collapsed/made invisible and the new set of subrows be expanded.

I am mainly a code-behind-person and not so used to client-side scripting. I have experimented with several approaches, but so far not succeeded. I have read a couple of suggestions but they are all slightly different and not directly applicable. This is my current attempt:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 30%; vertical-align: top;">
            <table id="myTableTree" style="width: 100%;">
                @foreach (var testSuite in Model.TestSuites)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left;">
                            @Ajax.ActionLink(testSuite.Description, "GetContent", new { testSuiteId = testSuite.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "subContent" }, new { onClick = "setShowState(" + testSuite.Id + ");" })
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    foreach (var testCase in testSuite.TestCases)
                    {
                    <tr itemprop="@testSuite.Id" style="display: none;">
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            @Ajax.ActionLink(testCase.Description, "GetContent", new { testCaseId = testCase.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "subContent" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                }
            </table>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;" id="subContent"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setShowState (testSuiteId)
    {
        var rows = document.getElementById('myTableTree').rows;
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
        {
            var row = rows.item(i);
            if (row.attributes['itemprop'] == testSuiteId)
                row.style.display = 'block';
            else
                row.style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
</script>
```

As you see all subrows are initially set as display=none. I grabbed an arbitrary attribute to hold the first level id on each second level row. itemprop seemed to be as good as any. On the first level row I added an onClick call referencing a javascript function. The intention of the setShowState function is to loop all rows and set appropriate visibility for the rows. When I check the resulting page source it looks the way I expected, but does not work. Subrows are never expanded.

1) Is it OK to set initial server returned row display=none and then toggle on client side?

2) Is it OK to have the actionlink trigger an ajax server call AND also trigger a client side script to set visibility? Or would it be better to move the ajax call to the java script to have only one call?

3) Is it better to toggle by using display=block/none or visibility=visible/collapse? Would it actually be any difference?

4) Is it OK to use itemprop to store the parent id? I see that many use class attribute for similar cases. Can class attribute be used with pure integer values?

5) What is the fastest way to toggle rows the way I want? Is looping all rows too slow? I will have 10-20 header rows with 2-10 sub rows each.

6) Is the whole design bad? I did not find a treeview control in the MVC toolbox, so therefore I decided to go this way. I think this looks at least as nice as a treeview, but maybe another approach would have been better?

7) Would jQuery be of any help? I have the jQuery library included in the layout page, but I don't know how to make use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many times before it is very clarifying to express a detailed question. After checking slightly more I realized I just missed the syntax for parsing the attribute. This example is now fully working:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 30%; vertical-align: top;">
            <table id="myTableTree" style="width: 100%;">
                @foreach (var testSuite in Model.TestSuites)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left; border: 0;">
                            @Ajax.ActionLink(testSuite.Description, "GetContent", new { testSuiteId = testSuite.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "subContent" }, new { onClick = "setShowState(" + testSuite.Id + ");" })
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    foreach (var testCase in testSuite.TestCases)
                    {
                    <tr data-testSuiteId="@testSuite.Id" style="visibility: collapse;">
                        <td style="width: 10%; border: 0;">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="border: 0;">
                            @Ajax.ActionLink(testCase.Description, "GetContent", new { testCaseId = testCase.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "subContent" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                }
            </table>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;" id="subContent"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Toggle each section independantly
    function setShowState(testSuiteId) {
        var rows = document.querySelectorAll('[data-testSuiteId="' + testSuiteId + '"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var row = rows.item(i);
            row.style.visibility = (row.style.visibility == 'visible') ? 'collapse' : 'visible';
        }
    };

    // Alternative algorithm
    // Always collapse previous section when a new one is selected
    function setShowState2(testSuiteId) {
        var rows = document.getElementById('myTableTree').rows;
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var row = rows.item(i);
            if (row.getAttribute('data-testSuiteId') == testSuiteId)
                row.style.visibility = 'visible';
            else if (row.getAttribute('data-testSuiteId') != null)
                row.style.visibility = 'collapse';
        }
    };
</script>
```

I suggest the following answers to my own questions:

1) Yes, it is perfectly fine to set attributes and then toggle on client side.

2) Yes, it seems to be fine to trigger one server-side action and simultaneously one client-side.

3) I tried. In my case it seems to work equally fine with both: display and visibility. From reading further I understand display is to be used in most cases but visibility is slightly better in tables as table attributes like sizing will not need to be recalculated.

4) itemprop attribute works. But in HTML5 it is recommended to use the data attribute. So I exchanged "itemprop" with "data-testSuiteId".

5) There might be faster ways, but this looks acceptable to me.

6) Alternative controls?

7) The same can be accomplished with jQuery. That will make the code more compact and actually also faster.

```
// Toggle section
function setShowState(testSuiteId) {
    $("[data-testSuiteId='" + testSuiteId + "']").toggle();
};

// Display one section and collapse all others
function setShowState(testSuiteId) {
    $("[data-testSuiteId]").hide();
    $("[data-testSuiteId='" + testSuiteId + "']").show();
};
```